# Finding the magnitude of polarization vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, polarization, dielectric

Find the magnitude of the polarization vector P in a dielectric material with epsilon r = 2.8 if D = 3.0 X 10-7 dC / m2. 
Are the details in the question very less to answer the question. Is there some value missing, or we can find the polarization vector with the given values only ?

Answer (score 1):

In Gaussian units $D=E+4\pi P$, so $4\pi P=(\epsilon-1)E=(\epsilon-1)D/\epsilon$.